# print_r is not formatting output correctly in a browser

Tags: php

I'm using `print_r` for an array but it's not printing it in a "human readable" way in the browser. It's just printing as if I echoed:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [uid1] => 012345 [uid2] => 012345 ) [1] => Array ( [uid1] => 012345 [uid2] => 622279 ) [2] => 012345 ( [uid1] => 012345 [uid2] => 012345 ) [3] => Array ( [uid1] => 012345 [uid2] => 012345 )
```

etc.

What's causing this?

Comment: Besides to correct answers here (using `<pre>`), alternatives are setting a `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` if it will be the only output, or when on a development server, install `xdebug` which will give you nicely html-formatted dumps and loads of other advantages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're outputting it to the browser, do this:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($value, true) . "</pre>";
```

The tabulations and carriage returns are not rendered as such in HTML, unless inside a `<pre>` block.

Comment: This is partially true. Tabs and returns are not ignored, though.

Comment: Or simply view source (ctrl+u).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var_dump($array)` or a `echo nl2br(print_r($array, true));`

Answer (score 1):

Browsers automatically **collapse all line breaks, tabs, and spaces** in between the characters **into a single space**, which produces the "not as readable" output. In order to preserve all these, try wrapping your `print_r` output in `<code><pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

right-click with the mouse on the page and hit "View Page Source" you should see the original text...

Answer (score 0):

If your code has no the mission to generate pretty html view, for example, you just working with the some class, you can avoid the `pre` wrapping by sending `header("Content-type: text/plain")`. All output will be pre-formatted like monospaced text with the `\n` line breaks.
In other cases, the better way is using output in Log file. Log files might be view by external application, like the "Console" on a Mac.